# Adding data to GraphViewSeries

Tags: android-graphview

I have a working app using Graphview in Android Studio. API 18 using com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.3
 When I try to add data that has `(x(I+1) b- x(I)) < 0` the app crashes with "Unfortunately. app has stopped.
 Is this a bug or are negative deltaX not allowed?
 Here is a sample

```
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
 new GraphViewData(1, 40)
 , new GraphViewData(2, 12)
 , new GraphViewData(3, 7)
 , new GraphViewData(2, 8) //note negative delta x
 , new GraphViewData(4, 10)
        });
```

Comment: I got a trick to work. In this case there were always 5 data points to make 4 line segments. So I broke the one graph of 4 segments into 4 graphs of 1 segment. With 4 graphseries if any of the delta Xi were negative then flip the X and Y values for that graphseries.To redraw graph add 4 graphseries to a graphview . I'm moving the graph segments to set the position of a robotic arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not allowed - that's [how it's documented](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/GraphViewSeries.html) to work:

> `values` - the values must be in the correct order! x-value has to be ASC.

Comment: Thank you. When I went back and read the documentation more slowly, I found that info. So I came up with a work around mentioned above.